# Is passing variable number of arguments feature- function overloading?

Tags: c

Using stdarg.h we can have function call with variable number of arguments. Is this also classified as function overloading?

Comment: What will this classification gain you ?

Comment: I think this is purely a question of what "overloading" means. Personally I would not call this overloading, but it **is possible** to implement an ugly version of overloading in C using the preprocessor with variadic macros and hideous hacks to test the types of arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, function overloading has the implication that a different instance of a function/method is invoked depending on the given parameters.  With variable arguments in C, the same function is called regardless of the parameter list.  So based on that, the answer would be, "No."  The function itself could of course mimic the behavior of overloading (do A if 1 argument, do B if 2 arguments, etc.), but it probably would not normally be termed "overloaded".

Answer (score 1):

Really, the answer could be "yes" or "no", depending on your definition of "function overloading".

From the compiler's perspective, there is only one function instantiated.  From the user's persepctive, you *could* call this "overloading", but it's enforced by neither the language nor the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the implementation, no the compiler doesn't create overloads. Variable argument functions use va_start/va_arg/va_end to get their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Overloading means that a different function will be called depending on the number and/or type(s) of the arguments (some languages can also use the return type).  But in this case, you're calling the *same* function regardless of the number of arguments.

It's no more overloading than `func(42)` vs. `func(43)`.

Note that C99 does have something that *behaves* much like a narrow form of overloading.  If you have `#include <tgmath.h>`, then `sqrt(x)` will call one of three different functions (`sqrtf()`, `sqrt()`, or `sqrtl`()), depending on the type of `x`.  But that's actually a "type-generic *macro*", not an overloaded function.  C11 adds the `_Generic` keyword, making this facility available to user-written code.  But that's not related to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a straight no since C doesnt implement function overloading as is. It may allow you to alter an argument or two but internally what takes place isnt the actual mechanism of function overloading.

> When an overloaded function is called, the C++ compiler selects the
>   proper function by examining the number, types and order of the
>   arguments in the call. Function overloading is commonly used to create
>   several functions of the same name that perform similar tasks but on
>   different data types.

I dont really understand your question but in general function overloading depends upon the difference in the arguments.

The arguments of the method.

public int add(int a, int b)

public float add(float a, float b)

This is function overloading. Atleast one of the arguments has to change for the function to be overloaded. This is not possible in early versions of c has they dont identify the functions by the types of parameters being passed.

Comment: Not much of an answer IMO ("C doesnt support function overloading") but would like to point out that typically the return of the functions doesn't count ;)

Comment: ok may i rephrase that C doesnt actually implement the function overloading concept the way it should be

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an example of function overloading.

True overloading implies that you have several *different* functions with the same name, but distinguished by their argument lists.  Depending on the arguments you pass, a different function instance will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

*[Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)* means having several contracts tied to a same name.
For example:

```
int a(int i1, int i2);
int a(char c);
int a();
```

This doesn't exist in C as a symbol has to be unique within a same scope, but this exists in C++.

So even if it can be called several ways, with different parameters types and numbers, the
 function `int a(int i, ...);` cannot be seen as overloading in C as there is only one contract, which is "*give me the arguments you wish and I'll find a way to handle them*".

But this function can be seen as an overloading in C++ in such a case:

```
int a(int i, ...);
int a();
```